# use embedded icc profile in an image for color correction

Tags: python, colors, python-imaging-library

I have an image with embedded icc profile, I need to use it along with another icc profile to make a new image for the purpose of color correction.

Currently, the workflow, as implemented in littleCMS in C, is as follows (skip error checking):

```
// image = imread( ... );  // load an image
hSourceProfile = cmsOpenProfileFromFile(argv[0], "r"e); // load the source icc profile, which can be embedded in
// an image so when the image is loaded, the icc profile can also be loaded, to simplify, I use the file here
hTargetProfile = cmsOpenProfileFromFile(argv[1], "r");
xform = cmsCreateTransform(hSourceProfile, TYPE_RGB_FLT, hTargetProfile, TYPE_RGB_FLT, INTENT_RELATIVE_COLORIMETRIC, cmsFLAGS_NOOPTIMIZE);
```

Now I don't know how to use the "xform" to transform the image (in which the source icc profile is embedded) to another one,
so new image will have different color. I see PIL (PILLOW) having a module ImageCMS, which appears to be a wrapper of
littleCMS.  But I don't know what equivalent ImageCMS commands are to the above littleCMS commands.

I expect a new image with same width, height, channels but with different color after the `xform`.

Thanks in advance